# Automated tests using MessageBox with MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel

Tags: c#, winforms, automated-tests, messagebox, white-framework

I'm using the TestStack.White framework for a WinForms .Net 2.0 C# application's coded automated regression tests. I have no problem handling OK/Cancel message boxes (`MessageBox.Show(...)`) but I'm having trouble handling the Yes/No buttons when using `MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel`. Thing is, I do not know what the button names are.

These work in my test jigs:

```
    public ButtonTestJig OkButton
    {
        get { return new ButtonTestJig(Window, "okButton"); }
    }

    public ButtonTestJig CancelButton
    {
        get { return new ButtonTestJig(Window, "cancelButton"); }
    }
```

Does anybody know the equivalent "cancelButton" for the NO button and the equivalent "okButton" for the YES button? Or perhaps even better, how to find them. My googling failed me.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to know the button names? `MessageBoxButtons` goes in, `DialogResult` comes out.

Comment: Avoid testing MessageBox, it doesn't have a bug.

Comment: Thx guys, we are not testing the MessageBox. This is not a 'unit test' or a component test. It is an application regression test. A series of tests to test that buttons cause things to happen ... etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/releases/view/11366 or inspect.exe (which comes in the windows SDK to see what the automation Id's for those controls are.